# How to identify an HTML element's selector using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a nav bar, where if you hover over an `a` item in the nav bar, it will add a class named `nav-hover` that adds certain styling to `a` when hovered.

Let me know if there is a better way to implement this, but in each `li`, I have added it's unique selector inside ````` navIn()````. Which method can I use that would automatically extract the selector. Using `````this``` didn't work.

```js
function navIn(obj) {
  document.querySelector(obj).classList.add('nav-hover');
}

function navOut(obj) {
  document.querySelector(obj).classList.remove('nav-hover');
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
  <div class="container" id="nav-position">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li onmouseover="navIn('#nav-position > ul > li:nth-child(1)')" onmouseout="navOut('#nav-position > ul > li:nth-child(1)')"><a data-scroll href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li onmouseover="navIn('#nav-position > ul > li:nth-child(1)')" onmouseout="navOut('#nav-position > ul > li:nth-child(2)')"><a data-scroll href="#work">My Work</a></li>
      <li onmouseover="navIn('#nav-position > ul > li:nth-child(1)')" onmouseout="navOut('#nav-position > ul > li:nth-child(3)')"><a data-scroll href="#">Resume</a></li>
      <li onmouseover="navIn('#nav-position > ul > li:nth-child(1)')" onmouseout="navOut('#nav-position > ul > li:nth-child(4)')"><a data-scroll href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use css `a:hover { //Your styling here}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to achieve the same hover effect:

**EDIT:** You can achieve the underline effect with just CSS. You can create the underline using [`pseudo-elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and apply transition effects onto it as shown below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

/* Set the position on your <a> tag so the pseudo-element will position relative to it. */
.nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

/* Create the underline element for each <a> tag */
.nav-link::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
}

/* Apply the :hover pseudo-class on the pseudo-elements */
.nav-link:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Work</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I am aware of this, but I want a new class to be added on top of the a tag when hovered over. I can't achieve that in pure css. I want a fancy underline transition to appear when hovered over.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the underline transition.